# Asp.net Jquery does not work get update

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to update data with ASP.NET JQUERY AJAX call

But it doesn't update data.

How can I solve this error  ?

**Javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Guncelleme Alanı Oluştur
        function guncellemeolustur(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AsynUygulama.aspx/guncellemealani",
                data: "{id:'" + id + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#" + id).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                        $(this).html(msg.d)}).fadeIn("slow");
                }
            });
        }
```

**HTML Markup**

```
  <div>
     <h2>Departman Tablosu</h2>
       <table border="1">
         <thead>
           <th>Departman Adı</th>
           <th style="text-align: center;">İşlem</th>
           <th style="text-align: center;">İşlem</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
          <asp:Repeater ID="Repeat1" runat="server">
            <itemtemplate>
               <tr id='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>
                 <td><%# Eval("Ucret") %> -  <%# Eval("ParaTipi") %></td>
                 <td><%# Eval("YasGrubu") %></td>
                 <td>
                   <input type="button" onclick="guncellemeolustur(<%# Eval("ID") %>)" value="Güncelle" />
                   <input type="button" id="silbtn" style="margin-left: 10px;" onclick="silkayit(<%# Eval("ID") %>)" value="Sil" />
                 </td>
               </tr>
             </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
         </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
```

**WebMethod**

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string guncellemealani(Int32 id)
 {
    SiteDB system = new SiteDB();
    string sonuc = "";

    SqlConnection bg = system.baglan();
    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("select * from TurCocukFiyat where ID=@id", bg);

    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    bg.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();

    sonuc = "<input id=guncelle type=text value=" + dr["TurAdi"].ToString() + " /><input type=button value=Güncelle onclick=guncelleislemi(" + id + ",document.getElementById('guncelle').value) />";

    bg.Close();

    return sonuc;                 
 }
```

Code that perform the update:

**Javascript**

```
 //Guncelleme Islemi Gerceklestirir
    function guncelleislemi(id, kayit) {
       $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "AsynUygulama.aspx/guncellemeyap",
              data: "{kayit:'" + kayit + "', id:'" + id + "'}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (msg) {
                  usercontrolgetir("AsynUserControl.ascx");
              }
         });
     }
```

**WebMethod**

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string guncellemeyap(Int32 id, string kayit)
 {        
   SiteDB system = new SiteDB();
   SqlConnection bg = system.baglan();
   SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("update TurCocukFiyat set ID='" + id + "' and BirimAdi=" + kayit, bg);

   bg.Open();
   komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
   bg.Close();

   return "guncelleme basarili";
 }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: when ı click the update button , ı cannot any process update

Comment: Are you able to call method, try to debug and track whether breakpoint occurs?

Comment: Your Web method doesn't include any update calls to SQL. Are you referring to data in your database or as it appears on screen in the UI

Comment: There are SQL i updated uo to text

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, please pass value of id without quotes, as accepting argument in webmethod is of type `int`

```
function guncellemeolustur(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AsynUygulama.aspx/guncellemealani",
        data: "{id:" + id + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#" + id).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).html(msg.d)}).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add the jquery ajax error callback with the following code:

```
function guncellemeolustur(id) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AsynUygulama.aspx/guncellemealani",
    data: "{id:" + id + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#" + id).fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).html(msg.d)}).fadeIn("slow");
    }
    error: function(jqXHR){
            glb = jqXHR; //creates a global var with the response from server
    }
});
}
```

now you can inspect the glb from the browser developer tools console.
take a look at the glb.responseText. it'll give you the error returned from server.
if the error doesnt help you please paste it here. maybe it'll help me\users analyze.